# How to move/rotate makehuman character in blender by adjusting value

Tags: animation, makehuman

I have a makehuman character exported to Blender and rigify addon turned on. I could use the mouse to move hand/legs of character. Since my character pose need precision, I couldnt get better results by using mouse based pose creation. How could I adjust the movement by adjusting values rather than using mouse to adjust values.

Or can anyone please elabrote on ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a bone (1), then press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties panel in the 3D Viewport. At the top of the panel, the transform menu contains WXYZ rotation which can be edited for precision (2).

[image]

Right click and press Insert Keyframes to add the values into keyframe.

[image]